# Have DataFrame repeat itself under timed duration

Tags: python, dataframe

I currently have a DataFrame that I would like to repeat onto itself. The current DataFrame looks like this...

```
   0
0  0
1  1
```

I would like to get it to repeat itself 5 times in five seconds to looks like the above version but with four more versions of itself under the same DataFrame. My current code is close but I want `final_df` to be the combined version of all five.

```
t_end = time.time() + 5
while time.time() < t_end:
    data = np.array([np.arange(2)]).T
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    time.sleep(1)
print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you tried appending the data frame:

```
t_end = time.time() + 5
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
while time.time() < t_end:
    data = np.array([np.arange(2)]).T
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    final_df = final_df.append(df)
    time.sleep(1)
print(final_df)
```